# Why isn't there just a plain Youtube scope in video lens

Tags: video, lenses, youtube

Why isn't there a regular Youtube scope in dash?  There is only Youtube education and Youtube Movies I think

Answer (score 2):

Try the alternative youtube lens found in this article:

[Alternative youtube lens](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/alternative-youtube-video-lens-updated.html)

I am using it & it is great.